# Is there any way to customize the color picker in HTML 5?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a website with HTML5 and CSS3, and I want to create a unique color picker with HTML5

Is there any way to customize the color picker?

Comment: No, not really. http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com/2011/01/html5-color-picker.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer...The only thing I found was a variety of jquery plug-in's..   :-)

Comment: It's a relevant question. With the HTML5 tag <input type="color"> comes a built-in colorpicker which defaults to a certain design. The question is: can it be customized and, in that case, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Opera, the only browser to have implemented the `color` element, you can customize the set of colours offered with a `datalist`:

```
<datalist id="greyscale">
    <option value="#000000">
    <option value="#333333">
    <option value="#666666">
    <option value="#999999">
    <option value="#cccccc">
</datalist>
<fieldset class="col">
    <legend>Color element 2</legend>
    <label for="excolor2">Color: </label>
    <input type="color" id="excolor2" name="excolor2" list="greyscale">
</fieldset>
```

[Here's some examples](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/dhDhL/).