# Styling color/date input window

Tags: html, css

Can you style the input boxes that will appear when using `input` with `type` of `date` or `color`, and if so, how?

```html
<input type="color">
<input type="date">
```

@edit

Since some of you are getting confused and maybe rightfully so, I don't mean to edit the initially visible `input` button, but rather the dialogue window that pops out in the browser when you click the input.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any style options for the HTML5 Date picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946091/are-there-any-style-options-for-the-html5-date-picker)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to customize the color picker in HTML 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033376/is-there-any-way-to-customize-the-color-picker-in-html-5)

Comment: @ksav the post you linked indeed partially answers my question, however it was posted 7 years ago and even if the answer didn't change I'd rather not base my opinion on such an old answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The popup windows box are system objects, and not subject to CSS. To style them you need to mimic the functionality in a custom popup.

You can do endless customization for the input button using CSS.

```css
input[type='date']{
padding:5px;
border: 1px solid green;
color: red;
background-color: yellow;
}

input[type='color']{
padding:5px;
border: 1px solid green;
color: red;
background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<input type="color">
<input type="date">
```

Comment: What I ment to apply the css to are the windows that will pop up when clicking those specific inputs, not the inputs themselves

Comment: The popup windows box are system objects, and not subject to CSS. To style them you need to mimic the functionality in a custom popup.